# jQuery how to trigger an if statement on windw load

Tags: jquery, load

I have the following code which, displays a drop down list if a certain option is selected within

```
// Hide Dealer drop down list
$(".which_dealer").hide();
// if Dealer is chosen then show Dealer drop down list
$('#from_dealer').bind('change', function (e) { 
    if( $(this).val() == 9) {
        $('.which_dealer').slideToggle('slow');
    }
    else{
        $(".which_dealer").hide();
    }         
});
```

This works great but I need to also account for users revisiting this page to edit it. Therefore if they have previously chosen this option then the .which_dealer list should not be hidden.

To do this I'd like to write an if statement that triggers on window load. I've tried but I don't know what function to use hence I have "load" twice. Please see below for my attempt.

```
// if Dealer was chosen chosen previously then show Dealer drop down list
$(window).load('load', function (e) { 
    if( $('#from_dealer').val() == 9) {
        $('.which_dealer').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.which_dealer').hide();
    }         
});
```

Comment: The way I see it, I think you may be overthinking things. Post some markup or a fiddle example so I can be sure.

Comment: why not use cookies with this?

Comment: Hi, I'll try post a fiddle now, no idea how to use cookies. Cheers

Comment: is #from_dealer a hidden field ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/YLnhQ/

Comment: Hi, all just to let you know the developer here found a work around using PHP. I'm still curious on how to do it with jQuery but a solution has been found. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

try:

> $(document).ready( function(){
>             /* your code here */
>        } );

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save state from a user's previous visit to the web page (such as whether they've previously selected an option in that page) and then use that state in the web page the next time they visit, then you have the following options for storing the state so that it is available across different page visits:

1. Cookies
2. Local Storage
3. Storage on server

Cookies are ubiquitous in all browsers and fairly easy. They can be used to storage small amounts of data (typically less than 2k bytes)

Local Storage is really easy to use, but only supported in newer browsers.

Both cookies and local storage are connected with a particular browser on a particular computer, regardless of who the user actually is.

Storing something on the server typically stores the state on behalf of a logged-in user and then that state can be used for that user no matter where they login.

A cookie implementation might look like this:

```
// cookie functions
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}


$(document).ready(function() {

    // restore dealer state from previous cookie
    var lastDealerVal = readCookie("fromDealer");
    if (lastDealerVal) {
        $("from_dealer").val(lastDealerVal);
    }
    if (!lastDealerVal || lastDealerVal != "9") {
        $(".which_dealer").hide();
    }

    // if Dealer is chosen then show Dealer drop down list
    $('#from_dealer').bind('change', function (e) { 
        var val = $(this).val();
        createCookie("fromDealer", val, 60);
        if(val == 9) {
            $('.which_dealer').slideToggle('slow');
        }
        else{
            $(".which_dealer").hide();
        }         
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the info but I chatted to the lead dev and he does not want to use cookies for this. Sorry, I'll def take a look tho. Cheers

Comment: @ClintonGreen - how does the lead dev propose that you save this state then?

Comment: Hi, he is storing the info in a database. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(function(){ /* your code here */ } );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).load(function (e) { 
    if( $('#from_dealer').val() == '9') {
        $('.which_dealer').show();
    }
    else{
        $('.which_dealer').hide();
    }         
});
```